# Can firebug tell me the javascript name of an object?

Tags: javascript, firebug, names

I've been adding quite a bit of javascript to my pages lately, but have learned it all in classic seat-of-the-pants fashion.  When I want my page to do something, I google and experiment until I get the result I want.

I frequently have objects in my pages that I want to activate/deactivate, hide, show, etc., but - having missed the rigorous introduction to javascript - I've no idea how these things get named.  I click on objects with firebug open, expecting to see some fully-qualified name for the object, but get no joy.  I just need to be able to do something like form.button.value="something", and need to know the name of that object.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: In JavaScript, even functions can be anonymous. Can you explain with some code what you're having trouble doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst you are running Javascript code, you have all the local variables in the current scope, so if you had the following code:

```
var myObject = New Object();
myObject.Person = New Object();
myObject.Person.Name = "Mark";
myObject.Person.Gender = "Male";
myObject.Name = "object1";
```

... your root object would be myObject, and you refer to descendent objects through the dot notation.

However, thanks to the implementation of the DOM in the browser, you also inherit the `window` object via the `this` keyword.  In fact, you can leave the `this` keyword out for simple situations i.e. when you are not using closures.  Therefore, you can access Javascript functions at the top level by just using the function name.

If you want to access specific elements, like it sounds like you are wanting, you need to learn the DOM, and not use the syntax that you were suggesting (that sounds like 1990s Javascript).  The root element you need to know is the `HTMLDocument` object, accessed via the `document` property.  You can discover elements with specific `Id` (not `Name`) attributes by using the `getElementById` method of the document element.  Of course, it helps if you've given your element an unique Id from the start.  You can also recursively use the `childNodes` collection to iterate manually through elements until you find what you want.  Alternatively, if you really can't supply an Id, you could also use the `getElementsByTagName` method, which is attached to every element in the DOM.

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE></TITLE>
    <META NAME="Generator" CONTENT="TextPad 4.6">
    <META NAME="Author" CONTENT="?">
    <META NAME="Keywords" CONTENT="?">
    <META NAME="Description" CONTENT="?">
    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="Javascript">
        <!--

        function DoSummat()
        {
            var divInside = document.getElementById("Inside");
            divInside.textContent = "This text will appear inside.";
        }

        //-->
    </SCRIPT>
</HEAD>

<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000" LINK="#FF0000" VLINK="#800000" ALINK="#FF00FF" BACKGROUND="?">
<FORM>
    <INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" onclick="DoSummat();" NAME="MyButton" VALUE="Press Me">
</FORM>
<DIV ID="Outside">
    <DIV ID="Middle">
        <DIV ID="Inside"></DIV>
    </DIV>
</DIV>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 1):

Elements are generally identified using the `id` attribute. Example:

```
<input type="submit" id="saveButton" value="Save" />
```

You can use the `getElementById` method to get a reference to an element:

```
var b = document.getElementById('saveButton');
b.value = 'Saving...';
```

Answer (score 1):

Well since you gave the `form.button.value="something"` example, I'm guessing you want to control HTML objects. You can assign them an id, e.g.: <form id="my_form"... and then get elements by id from JS, as the function is even called, getElementById().

```
document.getElementById('my_form').button.value = 'something';
```

Answer (score 0):

You're question is extremely vague so I can't give you the answer you need.

`Object`s can't be "activated"/"deactivated" and they don't have "names" (they can have a `name` property, if that's what you mean).

For example, given:

```
var foo = {};
```

`foo` is a *variable* that happens to have a value that is an object. The object is not the variable (object having a "name"). Given:

```
bar = foo; foo = null;
```

`foo` is now `null` and the object that foo held is now stored as `bar`.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do that. The variable name isn't tied to the variable, and they're not passed between functions. The best you could do is write a function to take a string and resolve it back to a variable:

```
function printVar(name) {
    console.log(name + ": " + window[name]);
}
```

Of course, there's a *lot* of things wrong with this. I'd recommend just making two logging calls:

```
console.log("foo");
console.log(foo);
```

or, using the printf-style syntax:

```
console.log("foo: %o", foo);
```